# Backtracking not showing anything

Tags: pascal, backtracking

I want to find all the posibilities of moving around these numbers 1,2,3,4,5 with the conditions that "4,3" is not possible and 1 and 5 can't be in the same solution. I have this code but when I compile it it doesn't show me anything.

```
var  x:array[1..50] of integer;
i,k:integer;
avems,evalid:boolean;

procedure init;
begin
  x[k]:=0;
end;

procedure succesor;
begin
  if x[k]<5 then avems:=true
    else avems:=false;
  if avems=true then x[k]:=x[k]+1;
end;

function solutie:boolean;
begin
  if k=3 then solutie:=true
    else solutie:=false;
end;

procedure valid;
begin
  evalid:=true;

  for i:=1 to k-1 do
    if (x[i]=1) or (x[i]=5) and (x[k]=1) or (x[k]=5) then evalid:=false;

  if (k>1) and (x[k-1]=4) and (x[k]=3) then evalid:=false;
end;

procedure tipar;
begin
  for i:=1 to 3 do
    write(x[i],' ');

  writeln;
end;

begin
  k:=1;
  init;
  while k>0 do
  begin
    repeat
      succesor;
    until not(avems) or (avems and evalid);

    if avems then
      if solutie then tipar
        else begin
          k:=k+1;
          init;
        end
        else k:=k-1;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Please provide the output of the program when you run it, and how it is different from what you expected.

Comment: the output is null, i'm not getting anything.

Comment: So write some more information so you can follow program flow, or debug. You might want to enable range checking too.

Comment: Please learn to properly format your code. If you'd learn to properly indent, it would make it much easier to follow the flow of the code. Also, learn to use the debugger; two minutes stepping through the code should show you exactly where the problem lies. (I'm going to suspect that it's because you fail to initialize properly, and you've got  a few places where you do nothing at times based on the value of some Boolean tests where I wager the behavior isn't what you intended.)

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect? Your code increments `x[1]` until it reaches 5, then sets `avems:=false;` and then decrements `k` to zero and exits the **while** loop.

Remember that Pascal does **not** use indentation for blocks like Python, so your
last steps are written more clearly as

```
if avems then begin
  if solutie then tipar
  else begin
    k:=k+1;
    init;
  end
end
else k:=k-1;
```

If this is not what you want, you have to code some `begin/end`.